# d3.json Not able to post data after $ value

Tags: java, javascript, json, d3.js

I am using d3.json to make request to java Controller.
While getting value in java script the data is coming correctly but while making request data after $ value is not going and truncating.Below is the code for the same.

```
alert(newPassword.value);

var jsonUrl="userinfoes?update=ByUserInfo&oldPassword=" + oldPassword.value + "&newPassword=" + newPasswordValue  + "&ajax=false"  ;

d3.json(jsonUrl,function(error,data){
                    alert(data);                    
});
```

While alert data is showing correctly as data$#124
but while request the data is passing as data$.
No data after $.

Answer (score 0):

You have written

```
var jsonUrl="userinfoes?update=ByUserInfo&oldPassword=" + oldPassword.value + newPassword=" + newPassword.value  + "&ajax=false"  ;
```

Above line has syntactical errors.

try with this

```
var jsonUrl="userinfoes?update=ByUserInfo&oldPassword=" + oldPassword.value +"&newPassword= "+ newPassword.value  + "&ajax=false"  ;
```

Check and reply, If you still facing problem.

Comment: Hey thanks saikiran
But that was a typo mistake.I am making the request same as you suggested but still facing the same problem.

Comment: try with this once,
var jsonUrl="userinfoes?update=ByUserInfo&oldPassword='" + oldPassword.value +"'&newPassword= '"+ newPassword.value  + "'&ajax=false"  ;

Comment: I have tried with above mentioned code while making request data after $ value is going but when i'm passing a special character after $ value is not going and truncating.